# MongoDb and Symfony2.4 file is not stored in Gridfs

Tags: file, symfony, file-upload, gridfs, doctrine-odm

I have implemented the file upload functionality with reference to this  link
http://www.slideshare.net/mongodb/mongo-db-bangalore-2012-15070802

But the file is not stored into the Gridfs.

I had done some research for the same and also with reference to this blog post 
http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/10/uploading-files-to-mongodb-gridfs-2/

But again, unfortunately, I stuck with this issue since last from 15 days

please help.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [KnpLabs/Gaufrette](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette) and the related [KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle)

The Gaufrette bundle provides a level of abstraction around file systems and, it helped me get file-oriented operations up and running quickly. I found it very useful, and in fact the Symfony CMS package leverages this bundle. It may help you out as well.